# Can't understand electromagnetic wave drawings if B = E/c

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

In an electromagnetic wave, if $B = \frac{E}{c}$, why on all the drawings I see values of maximum of both B & E to be represented equal?

see this image for example
https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fimpararelafisica.altervista.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F01%2Fonda-elettromagnetica2.jpg&f=1

In these drawing, B is drawn the same exact length of E... why?

Shouldn't the $B$ be much smaller than $E$

Comment: It depends on the units. Besides, the scale is made such that one can understand that E and B oscillate in phase perpendicular t each other

Comment: $B$ and $E$ have different units so you can't compare them. Which is larger, $2\, \mathrm{m}$ or $3\, \mathrm{s}$? Also, many people use units in which $E = B$.

Answer (score 0):

You have been confused by SI units which introduce the meaningless constants epsilonzero and muzero that have crazy, incompatible units.  As Javier pointed out, you can't compare E and B when they have different SI units.  In the Gaussian system of units, E and B have the same units, and are equal in an electromagnetic wave in vacuum where mu and epsilon each equals 1.  Since most physicists think in Gaussian units, even though they must teach in SI units, we naturally draw E and B as the same size arrow.

Comment: Units are like tools: use the right one for the job.